# Alternative image instead of alternative text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

How do I display an alternative image instead of alternative text?

Something like this:

```
<img src="image_i_want_to_display.png" alt="not_found_image.png"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Handle the `onerror` event in Javascript, set the `src` to your new image, and hope you don't recurse.

Answer (score 2):

In theory:

```
<object data="image_i_want_to_display.png">
    <object data="not_found_image.png">
        Still some alternative text because 
        some people turn images off and some
        people can't see
    </object>
</object>
```

In practise, browser support was pretty poor last time I tried it, but that was years ago.

You would almost certainly be better off making sure you didn't try to point people at things which aren't there.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what I'm thinking of is setting alternative image as a background

```
img {
    background: url('alternative-image.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: This could be a problem if the actual image loads slower than the alternative image, as the images will start replacing themselves and the effect would be annoying for the user. Also, keep in mind that this way two images are **always** loaded, rather than one, as the first answer implies.